# editor tracking updated in attribute table, but not in sql server database

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, attribute-table, trace

When I enable editor tracking and make modification on an object, I can find the edit user and edit time, but I cannot find the data updated in the sql server database. Is it because of the versioning? If yes when will the data updated in the sql server database? If no, what is wrong with my sql server database?

The following pictures are attribute table in ArcMap and table value in sql server.

[image]

[image]

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior with a versioned table. You must reconcile and post for the edit to reach the base table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that I am still in 10.1, if you reconcile and post, but there is a lock on the feature class, the dates and editors will not be posted to the business table. If you need to see the data immediately for reporting purposes or other pressing reason(s), you can see the editor tracking information in the Adds table (a table) for that particular feature class.

Also, any feature class that is registered as versioned has a view automatically created for it, which shows all records, including adds. You can view this in the Views under your database in SQL or add the view to your .mxd in ArcMap.